# Android Studio:Only one image is showing from json array

Tags: java, android, arrays

I want to load all images from "gallery" array but only one image is loaded, n also /length() is not working for array length.

i have provided json here please give code me if u can to load all "g_image" in viewpager or any slider

```
 private void LoadGalleryImages(ApiService apiService, String ProductId) {
        Gallery gallery = new Gallery();
        gallery.setId(ProductId);
         Call<ApiResponse<DataProduct>> galleryDetails = apiService.getGalleryDetails(gallery);
    galleryDetails.enqueue(new Callback<ApiResponse<DataProduct>>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<ApiResponse<DataProduct>> call, @NonNull Response<ApiResponse<DataProduct>> response) {
            SliderUtils sliderUtils = new SliderUtils();


            try {
                ApiResponse<DataProduct> resp = response.body();
                DataProduct gallerys = resp.getData();
                if (gallerys != null) {
                    Gallery gallery = gallerys.getGallery().get(0);
                    galleryCache = gallery;
                    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Image"+ i, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(gallery.getGalleryImage());

                    }
                    sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);


                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "ERROR RESPONSE" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
             viewPagerBannerAdapter = new ViewPagerBannerAdapter(sliderImg, getActivity());

            viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerBannerAdapter);

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<ApiResponse<DataProduct>> call, Throwable t) {

        }


    });
}
```

THIS IS JSON DATA

```
{
    "status": "success",
    "data": {
        "product": [
            {
                "id": "8917",
                "name": "test 5",
                "description": "Not Available",
                "price": "9999",
                "image": "image_link",
                "discounts_description": "",
                "discount": "0.00",
                "discount_type": "",
                "unit": "Piece",
                "url": "test-8917",
                "category_id": "356",
                "balance_qty": "0"
            }
        ],
        "relative_products": [],
        "gallery": [
            {
                "g_image": "image_link"
            },
            {
                "g_image": "image_link"
            },
            {
                "g_image": "image_link"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And also i cant get array length..(.length()) is not working

Data Product CLass

```
public class DataProduct {

    @SerializedName("product")
    @Expose
    private List<Product> product = null;
    @SerializedName("relative_products")
    @Expose
    private List<Product> relativeProducts = null;
    @SerializedName("gallery")
    @Expose
    private List<Gallery> gallery = null;
    public List<Gallery> getGallery() {
        return gallery;
    }

    public void setGallery(List<Gallery> gallery) {
        this.gallery = gallery;
    }



    public List<Product> getProduct() {
        return product;
    }

    public void setProduct(List<Product> product) {
        this.product = product;
    }

    public List<Product> getRelativeProducts() {
        return relativeProducts;
    }

    public void setRelativeProducts(List<Product> relativeProducts) {
        this.relativeProducts = relativeProducts;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "DataProduct{" +
                "product=" + product +
                ", relativeProducts=" + relativeProducts +
                ", gallery=" + gallery +
                '}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your `DataProduct` class?

Answer (score 0):

I SOLVED It !!

Changes i made are shown below.

```
try {
    ApiResponse<DataProduct> resp = response.body();
    DataProduct gallerys = resp.getData();
    if (gallerys != null) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            Gallery gallery = gallerys.getGallery().get(i);
            galleryCache = gallery;
            sliderUtils.setSliderImageUrl(gallery.getGalleryImage());
        }
     sliderImg.add(sliderUtils);
```